# c++ Debugging break in vector class

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, vectorization

Im trying to run my .exe but the application is crashing

Upon debugging I get the following break in the vector class. It breaks at this->Orphan_all.

Unhandled exception at 0x0562DF58 (msvcp120d.dll) in ExploringSfMExec.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.

```
void clear() _NOEXCEPT
    {   // erase all
    this->_Orphan_all();
    _Destroy(this->_Myfirst, this->_Mylast);
    this->_Mylast = this->_Myfirst;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Compile *all* your application with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) Then use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and look into the call stack (e.g. with `backtrace`)  Perhaps the reciever (i.e. `this`) is null?

Comment: This is the error. I am using windows visual studio 2010. Unhandled exception at 0x0562DF58 (msvcp120d.dll) in ExploringSfMExec.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.

Comment: We cannot debug your application with only 5 lines of code (the bug is likely elsewhere, perhaps in the caller function). You need to learn how to do debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the road, you have created an illegal `std::vector` pointer.

The following minimal program will reproduce the problem:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>* v;
    v->clear(); // will cause access violation in MSVC
}
```

`v->clear()` yields undefined behaviour, and MSVC turns this undefined behaviour into what you are experiencing.

That's really all we can tell you with the error description you have given to us. Since you are already using a debugger anyway, trace back the call to `clear` until you find the illegal pointer.

Comment: Thanks . The code I am using was run using opencv v2.3, I have opencv v2.10. Do you think this could be the cause?

Comment: @West1234: Anything could cause this error. It's as if you had a function like `void f(int i)` and asked us *"Why is this function called with 123?"* without showing us any calls of the function...